# PostgresDB: A view shows no content but the query of the view shows data

Tags: postgresql

Running into a strange problem with a Postgres DB:
Created a farely complex view eg.

psql> `CREATE OR REPLACE my_view AS SELECT "lots of joined tables"`.

If I use the view
psql> `select * from my_view;`

the result is no rows.

If I use the corresponding query

psql> `select "lots of joined tables";`

I got rows.

To me it looks like the state of the view is "INVALID".
In Oracle one can verify this. In Postgres there is no state.

Any idea how to track down the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the query you are running manually and the query from the view are exactly the same?  Perhaps you are getting objects from a different schema?  Postgres will not allow you to make a view invalid.

Comment: Yes: I do psql> \d+ my_view. Grab select and a where clause

Comment: Okay, so the view was fine, but there was an error in the copy/paste?  Postgres references dependent objects in views by id, not by name, and it's very picky about not allowing you to change things that would change the view.

Comment: Yes. With the manual extension of the where clause I messed it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that some of the tables/views used in the view have changed and you have to drop it and create again.
Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: This is also what I think. But how can I verify it?

Comment: Just did another test: Scripted the view and recreated with a different name.
Did the same test and run into the same result.

Comment: Did the view compile?

Comment: A view cant be (according my know-how) compiled in postgres. In Oracle one can.

Comment: Did it create without errors I meant :-)  I suppose it must have.

Comment: These errors are difficult.  Some object the view uses is probably invalid.  In these cases I just edit the view (comment out parts) and try to isolate the culprit.

Comment: Found it by removing view columns:
My manually added "where clause" was wrong. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you figured this out :-)